# Vue $el is undefined when testing with Mocha/Chai under meteor

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, vue.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm starting our unit test environment for our project, but we may have picked a combo that doesn't work well in a couple scenarios.

Our project runs under Meteor, the code for the UI is written in Vue and Coffeescript. The test environment we're trying to work with is Mocha & Chai. When I run the test suite, the command looks like this:

```
meteor test --once --driver-package=dispatch:mocha
```

From the examples around the internet, the following code *should work*:

```
const VueObject = Vue.extend(MyVueComponent);
const VueInstance = new VueObject().$mount();
chai.assert.ok(VueInstance.$el.textContent);
```

From that point, I could ask $el all sorts of questions for my test, however $el is undefined. I even tried waiting by using `Vue.nextTick()` and it's still undefined. In the examples I've found, they often talk about using webpack, but I heard meteor doesn't like using webpack.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Did we pick a hard combination to work with?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Make sure you are running your tests in the browser. If that doesn't work try manually adding the element when creating Vue app.

I was facing this same issue with Jest.

Initially, I thought I had to create the element manually when testing the app, so I did:

```
test("do things", () => {
    const vm = new Vue({
        el: document.createElement("div"),
        render(h) {
            return h(Hello);
        }
    });
    expect(vm.$el.textContent).toBe("heyo");
});
```

But then `document` was `undefined`. This lead me to discover that I should have been running my tests using `domjs` instead of `node`

```
"testEnvironment": "jsdom"
```

With this change in place, I even got rid of the `el` and it still works like a charm.